# Can't generate Android APK signed with APK v2 scheme

Tags: android, android-studio, apk

I'm trying to build an APK which is signed with new [v2](https://source.android.com/security/apksigning/v2.html) scheme. 
I'm using Android studio 2.1.3 also tried with Android 2.2 RC, gradle version that i have been using is 2.1.3.
Changed the compiled version to api 24 and build tools to 24.0.2 but still can't generate apk with v2.

I tried checking the app using the following command, 
adb shell pm dump  | grep apkSigningVersion

Everytim i get 'apkSigningVersion=1' and also can't find the magic “APK Sig Block 42” in the apk itself.

All i'm trying to do is generate an apk signed with v2 scheme. Can generate old jar signed v1 apks without any problem.

I want to know

1. what changes should I make to generate v2 singed apk's other than compiler changes.
2. Is there a tool to convert v1 signed old apk's to convert into v2 scheme.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taken from https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0.html#apk_signature_v2:

> Android 7.0 introduces APK Signature Scheme v2, a new app-signing scheme that offers faster app install times and more protection against unauthorized alterations to APK files. By default, Android Studio 2.2 and the Android Plugin for Gradle 2.2 sign your app using both APK Signature Scheme v2 and the traditional signing scheme, which uses JAR signing.

As this text states, you need to use Android Studio 2.2 (currently available as beta) and also update the Android Plugin for Gradle to the latest version.

Comment: Good to know that both schemes are used on v2-signed APKs.

Comment: have used 2.2 RC and gradle version 2.1.3 , https://services.gradle.org/distributions/ , 2.2 gradle version doesn't exist, 2.30 didn't work

Comment: scratch previous comment was able to generate with 2.20

Comment: For anybody confused: There is a difference between the Gradle version (That in the `gradle.wrapper` file, the currently latest is `3.0`) and the Android Gradle Plugin version (That in the project `build.gradle` file, the currently latest is `2.2.0-rc1`).

Comment: need help with a similar issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42587750/6144372 ...

Comment: I used  V1 (Jar Signature) and it's on playstore since 4 months ,so my question is **Can i change it to v2 schemed signed apk and does it any effect ?**