# Unable to sign apk "with only the traditional scheme" even after setting 'v2SigningEnabled' as false

Tags: android, android-studio, android-7.0-nougat, android-7.1-nougat, android-studio-2.3

I updated my `android-studio` to latest stable version i.e. 'Android Studio `2.3`' and also the `gradle` to `2.3.0`.

Now, when I am trying to generate a signed apk of my app's release build, this "extra" thing (Signature versions:) is getting shown in the last step:

[image]

I clicked on 'Signature Help' and this [page](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0.html#apk_signature_v2) got opened.

I followed the doc and made changes to my build.gradle file like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

//Put Fabric plugin after Android plugin
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    signingConfigs {
        config {
            keyAlias 'xxxxxx'
            keyPassword 'xxxxxx'
            storeFile file('/Users/xxxxx')
            storePassword 'xxxxxx'
            v2SigningEnabled false
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxxxx.xxx"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile('com.mikepenz:fastadapter:1.8.2@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.6@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and tried to generate the signed apk again but still this "extra" thing is getting shown.

**What** should I do now to sign apk "with only the traditional scheme"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you see in the top screenshot is the Android Studio wizard for creating a signed APK. What you want is to tick *only* the V1 (Jar Signature) checkbox. The other checkbox is for the new signing.

The setting you have in your `build.gradle` file does not affect what the Android Studio wizard shows to you. It only affects a build from the command line. So ticking V1 and then Finish will work just fine.

I do recommend to make your project ready for the new signing though, as it drastically reduces the installation time for your users (You would then tick V1 *and* V2 signing. V1 would be for backwards compability)

Comment: but on that link it says: `Caution: If you sign your app using APK Signature Scheme v2 and make further changes to the app, the app's signature is invalidated. For this reason, use tools such as zipalign before signing your app using APK Signature Scheme v2, not after.` What's this and how can this affect if I follow your answer and what's the use of `v2SigningEnabled false` then?

Comment: If you disable `v2Signing` and build from the commandline *or* do not tick the option in the wizard, this does not affect you. It is a mean of protection, to avoid someone from decompiling your app, do changes, recompile it and publish it in you name.
If you do not do something to your apk after building (like [redexing](https://github.com/facebook/redex)), you are good to go and should sign also with v2.
I hope that makes it clear; If you have any further questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: I used  V1 (Jar Signature) and it's on playstore since 4 months ,so my question is **Can i change it to v2 schemed signed apk and does it any effect ?**

Answer (score 1):

Please add

**v2SigningEnabled** false in your Sign In buil.gradle app File

[image]

[For More Detail Read Documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/nougat/android-7.0.html#apk_signature_v2)

Comment: what if we have android project in intellij idea structure?